# autoconf - how to generate template and copy it to proper directory

Tags: linux, makefile, autoconf, automake

I'm using autoconf & automake in a C project. I'd like to create a .deb package, so I have the following `control.in` file:

```
Source: myproject
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Maintainer: Paul Walker <pwalk@test.it>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>=9), autotools-dev@MORE_DEPENDENCIES@
Standards-Version: 1.0.0
Homepage: https://www.my-website.it/

...
```

I'd like to configure this file with autoconf since there might be `MORE_DEPENDENCIES` according to some configure-time flag I did set.

This `control.in` file sits in a `stubs/` folder, after substituting the `MORE_DEPENDENCIES` variable, I'd also like to copy the resulting `control` file into the final destination folder `debian/` to create the .deb package.

So essentially I'm trying to have autoconf do the following:

1. Include `{srcdir}/stubs/` as input folder in order to substitute macros in the `.in` file sitting there
2. Configure the stub `{srcdir}/stubs/control.in`, substitute whatever macro is in there, generate the file `{srcdir}/stubs/control` with substituted macros
3. Copy `{srcdir}/stubs/control` into the final destination folder `{srcdir}/debian/control`

I've been looking for examples or in the official documentation but still can't find how to configure a `.in` file outside of the root source folder.

Regarding 'how to copy the final file to the debian/ folder' I suppose I could use [a symlink](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Configuration-Links.html#Configuration-Links) ? Is there any better way?

Answer (score -1):

This is a top-of-the-foodchain problem.

The Debian packaging tools are designed to be the top-level tool for building Debian packages, and the control file is supposed to stay unchanged for the entire run of a package build. You can probably fudge your way around that if you only wish to build binary packages, but then there would be no point in modifying the build dependencies because they are evaluated earlier.

The normal build process will `distclean` the build tree in order to record changes in the source package, then rerun `configure` and build. If you update debian/control at this point, the results are undefined.

If you have to update debian/control programmatically, use a separate mechanism that is not reachable from the regular package build. If you have regular releases rather than cutting packages from development versions, it might even make more sense to treat the packaging as separate.